# expired acrylic paint?

Tags: paint, acrylic

Is it safe for me to use expired acrylic paint on canvas? if not is there a DIY on how to rid the mold or whatever is causing the sour smell in the paint? (i really dont want to spend $30 on more gold,silver,and copper paints.)

Comment: So, the paint smells bad/strange? How important to you is it that the results be good?

Answer (score 2):

It is "safe" but as the paint out-gasses it will continue to smell sour.

I used some older paint on a bathroom in a garage once and it continued to stink for months.

Only you can decide if the smell is worse than paying $30 for more paint.

Good luck!

Comment: I agree add some [mildewcide](http://www.natlallergy.com/index.php/mx-3-complete-mildewcide-paint-additive-7-5-oz-bottle.html?dfw_tracker=3542-690&gclid=CMmYl7mlscsCFYhqfgodfugIYw) it will help with the smell and prevent long term issues but it may smell for a while.